# Replacing NaN using pandas fillna

Tags: python, pandas

there's a dataframe, mat:

```
    x    y     z    d
0  1.0  1.0  4589  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  4716  1.0
2  0.0  NaN  4984  NaN
3  0.0  NaN  4673  NaN
4  0.0  1.0  4514  1.0
5  NaN  1.0  4614  1.0
6  NaN  1.0  4684  1.0
```

I was trying to fill the NaN with some values.So I tried

```
mat['x'].fillna(666)
print(mat)
```

but it returns:

```
    x    y     z    d
0  1.0  1.0  4589  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  4716  1.0
2  0.0  NaN  4984  NaN
3  0.0  NaN  4673  NaN
4  0.0  1.0  4514  1.0
5  NaN  1.0  4614  1.0
6  NaN  1.0  4684  1.0
```

I've tried `mat.fillna({'x':666})`  as well, but it made no difference.

while

```
gg = mat['x'].fillna(666) 
print(gg)
```

returns

```
     x    y     z    d
0  1.0  1.0  4589  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  4716  1.0
2  0.0  NaN  4984  NaN
3  0.0  NaN  4673  NaN
4  0.0  1.0  4514  1.0
5  NaN  1.0  4614  1.0
6  NaN  1.0  4684  1.0
0      1.0
1      0.0
2      0.0
3      0.0
4      0.0
5    666.0
6    666.0
```

and

```
xx = mat.fillna({'x':666})
print(xx)
```

returns:

```
0    1.0  1.0  4589  1.0
1    0.0  1.0  4716  1.0
2    0.0  NaN  4984  NaN
3    0.0  NaN  4673  NaN
4    0.0  1.0  4514  1.0
5  666.0  1.0  4614  1.0
6  666.0  1.0  4684  1.0
```

None of the returns above is what I want.How can I get this:

```
      x    y     z    d
0    1.0  1.0  4589  1.0
1    0.0  1.0  4716  1.0
2    0.0  NaN  4984  NaN
3    0.0  NaN  4673  NaN
4    0.0  1.0  4514  1.0
5  666.0  1.0  4614  1.0
6  666.0  1.0  4684  1.0
```

Comment: There are loads of dupes for this, the thing to take away is that most pandas ops return a copy, and nearly all have arg `inplace` so you need to either self-assign e.g. `df = df.fillna(0)` for instance or `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `inplace` or assign bact to column output:

```
mat['x'].fillna(666, inplace=True) 
print (mat)
       x    y     z    d
0    1.0  1.0  4589  1.0
1    0.0  1.0  4716  1.0
2    0.0  NaN  4984  NaN
3    0.0  NaN  4673  NaN
4    0.0  1.0  4514  1.0
5  666.0  1.0  4614  1.0
6  666.0  1.0  4684  1.0
```

Or:

```
mat['x'] = mat['x'].fillna(666) 
print (mat)
       x    y     z    d
0    1.0  1.0  4589  1.0
1    0.0  1.0  4716  1.0
2    0.0  NaN  4984  NaN
3    0.0  NaN  4673  NaN
4    0.0  1.0  4514  1.0
5  666.0  1.0  4614  1.0
6  666.0  1.0  4684  1.0
```

Comment: Thank u very much! It works. Interesting ! But why `gg = mat['x'].fillna(666) ` returns 7 new rows?

Comment: `7` ? Are you sure?

Comment: Oh, it's not easy to explain here. Can you see what I posted above? It's more clear.

Comment: I see it. because length of column is `7`

Comment: So the new data will contain the rows that it already has and add more new rows? The 'x' column has 7*2 =14 rows? why does it add the 7 new rows?So confusing...

Comment: No, it have only same number rows as `df`. It only apply function `fillna` for column ans return new column.

Comment: Oh,I see.My fault...Thanks~=.=

Comment: No problem ;) Nice day!